# phpunit: Cannot open file "FILENAME.php" when running with bootstrapping

Tags: php, phpunit

I created a new composer project in the wrong server, I have the following directory structure:

```
 PROJNAME (dir)
  --PROJNAME.php (my project file) 
  tests (dir)
  --PROJNAMETest.php
```

I've been running the following command which works on the wrong server:

```
vendor/bin/phpunit --bootstrap PROJNAME.php --testdox tests/
```

But after moving the files to the correct server (using scp -r, deleting vendor dir, and doing composer install), I get error:

```
Cannot open file "PROJNAME.php".
```

However when I am running without --bootstrap PROJNAME.php, it works without errors! I don't understand this.

Follows is content of PROJNAME.php:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';


function DummyMethod(){
}
?>
```

And for the file tests/PROJNAMETest.php:

```
<?php

require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

final class PROJNAMETest extends TestCase
{

public function testDummyMethod()
{
$this->assertEquals(true, true);
}
}
```

I will also point out that file permissions look the same on both machines:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 root root    69 Aug  9 21:07 PROJNAME.php
```

Since I work with root user, I don't see permissions as possible cause..

Please advice what could cause this...

Thanks!

Comment: "wrong" server?

Answer (score 0):

> I get error:
>
> ```
> Cannot open file "PROJNAME.php".
> ```

and

> However when I am running without --bootstrap PROJNAME.php, it works without errors! I don't understand this.

The error message "Cannot open file ..." is by intention. The message could be read as:

> Cannot open bootstrap file ...

The [*bootstrap file*](https://phpunit.de/manual/current/en/organizing-tests.html) is loaded before nearly everything else in the Phpunit testsuite(s) and it is to establish the bare-minimum project setup for testing. The error just shows that the bootstrap file could not be opened.

Keep in mind that you're using a relative path to the bootstrap file so you need to take care that this combined with the working directory of (the invocation of) the test-runner can resolve to the correct (readable) bootstrap-file. Unless it's not, you'll see this error. That error is by intention btw., not being able to open the bootstrap file is something you want to know about.

Just log into your correct server, change into the directory of the bootstrap file and execute the testsuite in that directory. It should work (unless the file can't be opened by yourself as the user within the file-system).

To overcome system differences, create yourself a `phpunit.xml`(`.dist`) file which has an attribute for the bootstrap file and execute the test-suite with that configuration file. Put it under version control so that you have the configuration managed and the setup in a more defined and stable manner.

But first find out why the file could not be opened.

Comment: Well, today I re-connected to the development server, and it just works, no such error anymore! I cant tell why.. perhaps re-logging on the server has set some env variables, I dont know... @hakre: Could you please at least explain the difference between bootstrapping "PROJNAME.php", and running without bootstrapping? I am using this to ensure the file is loaded before test cases run... is it really needed? After that I'll accept your answer as the solution I guess :)

Comment: See the bootstrap as a PHP include file that is included before the test-suite runs. This allows you to setup the PHP environment like you see fit, e.g. initialize autoloaders etc. . If you don't need a bootstrap file (your testsuite works w/o) then you don't need to make use of it. Don't use it if you don't need it so you can make use of it later when you need it :) - A common use-case is in composer based projects to use  the `vendor/autoload.php` file as bootstrap.